# I want to verify this property of limits

Tags: limits, analysis

[Just prior to the evaluation of derivative it is assumed that...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIsvp.jpg)

Is saying $x$ tends to $c$ same as saying $f(x)$ tends to $f(c)$ in the context of (rigorously) evaluating a limit? Consider $f$ to be a continuous real function and $c$ to be a point in its domain.

The example I am working on also has $f$ to be strictly increasing and differentiable with $f'(x)>0$ in its domain, but I want to know if the above proposition will hold without the second part of the context.

Comment: The limit that i wish to evaluate is in itself another function of f(x) like g(f(x)) what i want to know is whether i can write it as " limit of g(a) as a tends to f(c)"  instead of  "limit of g(f(x)) as x tends to c" . I apologize that i cannot properly format my question.

Comment: $\lim_{a\rightarrow f(c)}g(a)$ is equal to $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(f(x))$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $c$. That is basically the definition of continuity at $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formal proof that

$$ \lim_{a\rightarrow f(c)}g(a) = \lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(f(x))$$

whenever $f$ is continuous at $c$, assuming all limits exist. Let $L$ be the limit on the left side. Let $\varepsilon>0$. We wish to find $\delta$ such that

$$ |x-c|<\delta \implies |g(f(x)) - L|<\varepsilon $$

Applying definition of limit to the LHS limit, and taking $a=f(x)$, we find there exists $h>0$ such that

$$ |f(x)-f(c)|<h \implies |g(f(x))-L|<\varepsilon $$

Since $f$ is continuous at $c$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that

$$ |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<h $$

Combining these inequalities, we found a sufficient choice of $\delta$, proving the limit.

Note: I used the variable $h$ because it was playing two roles: for the LHS limit, it acts like $\delta$ in the epsilon-delta definition, but it acts more like $\varepsilon$ in the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i greatly appreciate it